# Could I make an entirely locally hosted app with WebView2/Winforms?

Tags: winforms, blazor, webview2

This might be a weird question but, I was thinking it would be cool to have access to Blazor in a desktop app. Is it possible for WebView2 to work with local Blazor WASM and html/css/javascript files or is it not designed for this?

Comment: Google for "blazor electron" and/or "blazor webwindow"

Comment: I also found references to a "Blazor Desktop" being in development but nothing has been said about it recently.

Answer (score 0):

You can user for example [ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/) which allow you host Blazor inside WinForms/WPF/MAUI